# Select records which are changes to a series (MySQL/rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, select

I have a table which records a series of values, as so ...

```
ID.   VAL
1.    18
2.    18
3.    20
4.    20
5.    18
```

I'm trying to work out how to select the records at which the series changes (e.g. Record 1, 3 and 5). I'm using rails, but I'm guessing raw MySQL might be the way forward.

Would appreciate any help you could offer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

What you want to do is self join it against itself, like this:

```
SELECT 
  records2.id
FROM 
  records AS records1
  JOIN records AS records2 ON (records1.id = records2.id-1)
WHERE
  records1.val != records2.val
```

Such that we join a record with the one preceding it. If the values for the two records differ - we have our answer.